# How to style Geofabrik shapefiles to resemble Open Street Map?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, style

I have downloaded the shapefiles for the UK from http://www.geofabrik.de/data/download.html
I have loaded the shapefiles in to QGIS.
Could someone please explain to me or point me in the direction of how to correctly style the shapefiles to resemble Open Street Map, I have tried to google it and all the .qml files I find don't seem to do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shapefiles from Geofabrik are only subsets of the full Openstreetmap database. You need the complete toolchain Postgis-Mapnik on the full data to get exactly the same style.

For use in QGIS, either use the QuickMapServices plugin to add an Openstreetmap basemap, or try the links given in the linked questions of the `Related` column on the right to style the shapefiles.